# Part of subsection title not in bold

Tags: fonts, section-titles

I have the following problem: I want to write a subsection title, which is partially not bold. I have found solution which showed that all subsections are not bold, but I don't want that. I want this in only one subsection.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    
\subsection*{Title}
\subsection*{Another title}
\subsection*{Another title but THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT BE BOLD}

\end{document}
```

And the output is this:

[image]

But what I want is this:

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: `\textmd{THIS IS NOT BOLD}`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The analogue of `\textbf` for medium (not bold) is `\textmd` so..

```
\textmd{THIS IS NOT BOLD}
```